# kendoui kendoGrid datasource aggregate to existing data

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I hope this question hasn't been asked elsewhere but I'm running into an issue with a kendoGrid and adding aggregates. This is an existing grid bound to a data Source that is an array.

What is the best way to add an aggregate to an existing data Source?

Here is what I'm doing to bind to the existing data Source:

```
var grid = $("#myGrid").data("kendoGrid");
grid.dataSource.data(myArray);
```

Answer (score 3):

Once you set the data you can add new aggregate like shown in the [documentation](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#methods-aggregate).

---

```
var dataSource= new kendo.data.DataSource({
  data: [
    { name: "Jane Doe", age: 30 },
    { name: "John Doe", age: 33 }
  ]
});
// calculate the minimum and maximum age
dataSource.aggregate([
  { field: "age", aggregate: "min" },
  { field: "age", aggregate: "max" }
]);
var ageAggregates = dataSource.aggregates().age;
console.log(ageAggregates.min); // displays "30"
console.log(ageAggregates.max); // displays "33"
```

Comment: Petur, thanks for the quick response. I've seen that item from the documentation. My problem is the values are set via an array that is set via an array. I've attempted the information above and I can't seem to access the aggregate values from the array. Any ideas?